# Chart JS - Title missing when clearing canvas if no data is available

Tags: javascript, chart.js

EDIT - Answer below worked fine, all I did aside from removing `chart.clear()` was to hide the legend and the x/y axes.

Any ideas what may be causing the blurry text now, though?

I'm sure I'm doing something remarkably silly, but I can't seem to figure this out.

I have the following global plugin that will display a "No data to display" message when applicable:

```
Chart.plugins.register({
  afterDraw: function(chart, args, options) {
    if (chart.data.datasets.every(dataSetContainsNoData)) {
        debugger;
        var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        var width = chart.chart.width;
        var height = chart.chart.height;
        chart.clear();

        ctx.save();
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
        ctx.fillText('No data to display', width / 2, height / 2);
    }
}
});
```

However, I would like to keep the title of this chart showing at the top, and can't figure out how to do it. If I inspect `chart.chart.options` the title option has the text set, and the display flag is set to `true`.

Here are the options that are on the actual chart.

```
options: {
        title: { display: true, text: 'Chart Header Text' },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to comment out `chart.clear()` and title should work.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. All I needed to do in addition was to hide the x and y axes. The last issue I can see is that my "No data to display" text has become quite blurry/not crisp. Any ideas what may be causing this? See my OP for a screenshot.

Comment: This can happen if you are adding your own css to the chart.